# Vue component error: Property or method X is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js

I have a fairly simple setup which is failing with these errors:

> Property or method "fruit" is not defined on the instance but
>   referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive
>   [etc.]
>
> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
>
> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Not sure whether it's because the x-template referencing method is buggy. I see it's not used much.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="main">

  <h1>Vue Component Prop Error</h1>

    <script type="text/x-template" id="foo">
      <p>{{fruit.name}}</p>
    </script>

    <my-thing :fruit="fruits[1]"></my-thing>

</div>

<script>
    Vue.component('my-thing', {
      template: '#foo',
      props: {
        fruit: Object
      }
    });

    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#main',
      data: {
        fruits: [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'apple'
        },{
            id: 2,
            name: 'banana'
        },{
            id: 3,
            name: 'carrot'
        }]
      }
    })
</script>
```

What am I missing? (I'd expect to see "banana" on the screen.)

Codepen: https://codepen.io/MSCAU/pen/WagOjz

Answer (score 3):

Move the `x-template` out of the `div` that the main Vue instance controls:

```
<div id="main">

  <h1>Vue Component Prop Error</h1>

  <my-thing :fruit="fruits[1]"></my-thing>

</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="foo">
  <p>{{fruit.name}}</p>
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmJzJO

Answer (score 1):

Having the template inside of #main is causing Vue to try to render it prior to when you want.

Moving the template outside of #main will allow it to be used as the template for `<my-thing>` without being rendered inside of #main.

```
<div id="main">
    <my-thing :fruit="fruits[1]"></my-thing>
</div>
<script type="text/x-template" id="foo">
  <p>{{fruit.name}}</p>
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NOLgBz

Comment: Two good answers at the same time. This works, thanks. Now where on earth is this documented? Not mentioned here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Inline-Templates

Comment: Good question, not sure if this specifically is documented. It's just something I know from experience and something you should expect.  You set your 'el' as '#main'.  So anything inside of #main will be rendered with the `app` scope.  `app` doesn't know you've defined that block as a template for `<my-thing>` or that it shouldn't try to evaluate `{{ fruit.name }}`.